# How to mock a class hierarchy

Tags: python, mocking

I want to mock a hierarchy of classes.  For example:

```
class Base(object):
    def one(self):
        return 'one'
    def two(self):
        return 'two'

class Derived(Base):
    def three(self):
        return 'three'
```

It is straightforward to define basic mocks:

```
from mock import Mock

def BaseMock():
    mock = Mock()
    mock.one.return_value = 'uno'
    mock.two.return_value = 'dos'
    return mock

def DerivedMock():
    mock = BaseMock()
    mock.three.return_value = 'tres'
    return mock
```

The above works, but it is incomplete.  I want to use the `Mock` arguments `spec` and `name`.  I can specify them as usual in `BaseMock`, but in `DerivedMock`, I have to modify private `Mock` attributes, which is bad form.

Is there a proper way to mock a hierarchy of classes complete with `spec` and `name`?

Comment: Why exactly is your presented approach bad form? In every approach, you'll need to construct a `Mock` that modifies `one`, `two` and `three`. So why is your current approach bad?

Comment: @Simeon Visser: The approach given above is incomplete because ``DerivedMock`` does not employ the Mock ``spec`` and ``name`` arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mock a class hierarchy, define the base class mock as usual:

```
from mock import Mock

def BaseMock():
    mock = Mock(spec=Base, name='BaseMock')
    mock.one.return_value = 'uno'
    mock.two.return_value = 'dos'
    return mock
```

In the derived mock, instantiate the base mock and (odious as it is) modify the Mock private attributes related `spec` and `name`:

```
def DerivedMock():
    mock = BaseMock()

    # Set Mock private attributes to Derived
    mock._mock_methods.extend(dir(Derived))
    mock._mock_name = 'DerivedMock'
    mock._spec_class = Derived

    mock.three.return_value = 'tres'

    # Defining DerivedMock.four would cause a spec error
    # mock.four.return_value = 'quatro'

    return mock
```

Now mock DerivedMock looks like class Derived, except that the return values are different:

```
d = DerivedMock()
assert isinstance(d, Derived)
assert repr(d).startswith("<Mock name='DerivedeMock' spec='Derived'")

assert d.one() == 'uno'
assert d.two() == 'dos'
assert d.three() == 'tres'
```